# Image Watch for cross platform

Tags: linux, visual-studio, opencv

I am using VS2017 to develop a cross platform (ARM linux) project with OpenCc and I would like to use "Image Watch" extension to debug my images.

I've installed the extension, but when I try to open the Image Watch window (while debugging) Visual Studio freezes, with no going back.

Is there any incompatibility between VS/Image Watch/Linux development that I am not aware of?

PS: I have also tried with VS2015 with the same result.